# Integration test with Flink union operator doesn't work as expected

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a union of 2 kafka topics and on the `union` I run a `KeyedProcessFunction`. However in the `processElement` method, I do not get all of the elements in the union.

In the integration test kafka is runnning as a `test container` and I'm using `MiniClusterWithClientResource` for the flink environment.

Topic A has 3 elements and Topic B has 2 elements.

In a gist the code skeleton looks like this

Create bounded kafka source so that the integration test can end

```
KafkaSource<T> sourceA =  KafkaSource.<T>builder().setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())... 

KafkaSource<T> sourceB =  KafkaSource.<T>builder().setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())...
```

Create DataStreams

```
DataStream<T> streamA = env.fromSource(sourceA, watermarkStrategy, sourceName) 

DataStream<T> streamB = env.fromSource(sourceB, watermarkStrategy, sourceName)
```

Create Union

```
DataStream<T> union =  streamA.union(streamB)
```

The job

```
DataStream<K> result = union.keyBy(someMethod()).process( new MyKeyedProcessClass()).name(someName);
```

When using `setBounded` the `processElement` is called for each of the 2 messages from both topic A and Topic B. i.e. it misses an message from topic A.

However when using `setUnbounded` the `processElement` is called for each the 3 messages from topic A and each of the 2 messages from topic B. i.e. it gets all of the messages but the job never terminates.

Is the behaviour expected?